# Splitting a pandas dataframe row and creating a new data frame

Tags: pandas

I have a data drame with two fileds of interest: docID, and categories.  Note the actual content is also a part of this dataframe along with other fields

JAN001   News, Sports

JAN212   Politics

FEB208   Business, News

I am trying to create a new dataframe with Pandas that looks like the following:

JAN001   News

JAN001   Sports

JAN212   Politics
...

I know I can loop thru the dataframe, but am new to pandas and think there is a way to do this more efficiently.  I have tried looking at several questions and trying various examples, but thus far have been unsuccessful.  I am also curious if an index is part of the solution, but have not explored this avenue yet.  Thanks for any help or advice.

---

UPDATE - here is the code and

{

```
foo = pd.read_csv("dtu_topic.txt", sep = "\t") 
foo = foo[:20]

print foo

#    id  dtu_docid                                          dtu_topic  \
#0   21523  2012-1553             Energy Taxation,State & Local Taxation
#1   21522  2012-1552            Legislation & Policy\Financial Services
#2   25470  2010-0227              Quantitative Economics and Statistics
#3   25477  2010-0215                        International Taxation\Asia
#4   21539  2012-1529  Ernst & Young Newsletters\This Week in Tax Reform
#5   25483  2010-0207                             State & Local Taxation
#6   21536  2012-1533             Payroll & Employment Tax\State & Local
#7   21537  2012-1532             Payroll & Employment Tax\State & Local
#8   24943  2010-0929  IRS Practice & Procedure,Tax Quality & Risk Ma...
#9   25500  2010-0185                      Financial Services Industries
#10  21542  2012-1524             Payroll & Employment Tax\State & Local
#11  21551  2012-1507                                   Personal Finance
#12  25523  2010-0159                      International Taxation\Europe
#13  21549  2012-1510             Payroll & Employment Tax\State & Local
#14  21557  2012-1501  Payroll & Employment Tax\Federal,Payroll & Emp...
#15  21558  2012-1498                   Accounting Methods & Inventories
#16  25567  2010-0104                                        Real Estate
#17  25529  2010-0152  Financial Services Industries,International Ta...
#18  21564  2012-1495                           IRS Practice & Procedure
#19  21563  2012-1494                   Payroll & Employment Tax\Federal

#parse dtu_topic into a list of categories
foo["dtu_topic_split"] = foo.dtu_topic.str.replace(',','\\')
foo["dtu_topic_split"] = foo.dtu_topic_split.str.split('\\').tolist()

# from example on stack overflow - get syntax error
dcm = foo[,list(dtu_docid = dtu_docid,
           dtu_topic = unlist(dtu_topic.split),
           by = 1:nrow(foo)]


                 #dt.2 <- dt[, list(Probe.Id = Probe.Id,
                 #                      Gene.Id = unlist(Gene.Id_split),
                 #                      Score.d = Score.d), by = 1:nrow(dt)]

#dcm = unlist(foo.dtu_topic_split)

print dcm
```

}

Comment: can you put the actual code of your frame up? e.g. an actual example (could be the text that you read in), this matters because the structure of the frame might matter

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to turn a frame of lists into something useful (your example only actually has 1 list in your column of interest)

try something like this

```
In [101]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = [['foo','bar','bah']], B = [['foo','bah']], C = [['foo']]),index=range(4))

In [102]: df
Out[102]: 
                 A           B      C
0  [foo, bar, bah]  [foo, bah]  [foo]
1  [foo, bar, bah]  [foo, bah]  [foo]
2  [foo, bar, bah]  [foo, bah]  [foo]
3  [foo, bar, bah]  [foo, bah]  [foo]

In [103]: concat(dict([ (row[0],row[1].apply(lambda y: Series(y))) for row in df.iterrows() ]))
Out[103]: 
       0    1    2
0 A  foo  bar  bah
  B  foo  bah  NaN
  C  foo  NaN  NaN
1 A  foo  bar  bah
  B  foo  bah  NaN
  C  foo  NaN  NaN
2 A  foo  bar  bah
  B  foo  bah  NaN
  C  foo  NaN  NaN
3 A  foo  bar  bah
  B  foo  bah  NaN
  C  foo  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Is there a way to query a dataframe for a item contained within a dataframe list field.  In my case a target Category "Personal Finance". And I would like to find all records where the target category is contained in the dataframe list field dtu_toipic_strip?   Or in the example above list all records where "foo" occurs in the original df field A.

Comment: no; using lists in a dataframe column, while supported, is quite inefficient, you are basically using python level calls for everything; this is the reason to avoid at all costs ``object`` dtype (which is what lists-in-a columns is). Much better to use a multi-level frame, and/or a set of different frames.